# Bookmarklet using document.body.search()

Tags: javascript, search, document, bookmarklet

I'm making a **bookmarklet** that checks the body for a specific string of text and runs a script when found. I'm using `document.body.search();` but it just gives the error message

`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'document.body.search('application is temporarily over its serving quota')')`

in the console. Am I using `search()` wrong? Should I be using something other than `document.body`?

**Javascript**

```
var prox='http://proxy-mirror.appspot.com/';
var prox1='http://toproxies.appspot.com/';
var prox2='http://meprxy.appspot.com/';
var prox3='http://i-love-proxy.appspot.com/';
var prox4='http://proxy0server.appspot.com/';
var prox5='http://proxy1server.appspot.com/';

var x=document.body.search('application is temporarily over its serving quota');

var url=window.location.href;

if(x!==-1) {
switch(window.location.hostname) {
    case 'proxy-mirror.appspot.com':url.slice(32);window.location.href=prox1+url;
        break;

        case 'toproxies.appspot.com':url.slice(29);window.location.href=prox2+url;
        break;

        case 'meprxy.appspot.com':url.slice(26);window.location.href=prox3+url;
        break;

        case 'i-love-proxy.appspot.com':url.slice(32);window.location.href=prox4+url;
        break;
        case 'proxy0server.appspot.com':url.slice(32);window.location.href=prox5+url;
        break;
        case 'proxy1server.appspot.com':alert('Whoops!\n\nIt seems this site is over its quota, and its the last proxy I have on the list\n\nSorry about that, please wait until tomorrow when the servers reset and you\'ll be good to go!');break;

}
} else {
window.location.href=prox+url;
}
```

Comment: Apparently `document.body.search` doesn't exist. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I don't think `document.body` has a search function. To check for snippets of text, you might have to iterate all the elements you're searching and compare them against your text string.

Answer (score 0):

The check should be:

```
document.body.textContent.indexOf('application is temporarily over its serving quota') > -1
```

There is no document.body.search but location.search() and it's not about searching for text. You've misunderstood docs.